# Is it possible to create foreign keys on master table of partitioning with PostgreSQL 9.6?

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys, database-partitioning, postgresql-9.6

If we create a master table and children with classic partitioning: check constraint on children, trigger to insert data into master to dispatch on children etc.

Is it possible to create another table and create some foreign keys directly on master and/or a specific child?

How to manage if not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found your question cause I had realized that my declared foreign keys on my master table are not working.

After doing some research to this topic I think this isn't possible on master table using PostgreSQL 9.6. So you must declare the foreign keys at each single partition to let them work - this should work

Comment: yeah same conclusion. Partionning is really for a specific subject and we can't create relationship because there is no inherited for index, constraints etc.PostgreSQL doesn't throw error when creating foreign keys or index, but they will not working.

Comment: Exactly. For ensuring for let foreign keys or e.g. unique indexes work overall partitions you must implement BEFORE INSERT triggers with checks against all partitions by your own. Maybe you should mark this answer as accepted or write an own answer and mark it as accepted